# Loading an image saved in a package in a jframe

Tags: java

I have looked through and none of the other answers on this site have worked for me. I need to load some pictures from another package in a jframe. All the jframe is for is to contain that image. This is my layout right now: javaproject/src/basic/main.java
For my images they are saved in here:
javaproject/src/image/thing.jpg

I have an array setup for multiple images. So i want this jframe to display the image[0] so it has to open and load the jframe with src/image/thing0.jpeg

Comment: `ImageIO.read(YourApplication.class.getResource("/image/thing.jpg"))`?

Comment: So, what have you tried, and where does it fail?